# How to implement complicated servlet mapping in web.xml descriptor

Tags: java, url-rewriting, struts2, web.xml

I faced with next task: I have an host, for example host.com and web-application on it.
Application written on Java (JSP/Servlets+Struts2).

I need to implement such HTTP-request to servlet mapping: if user enters address in browser like http://host.com/admin.action, where admin.action - existing action, defined in struts.xml, then render those struts2 action for user. If user enters something like http://host.com/abra-kadabra, (action abra-kadabra notdefined in struts.xml), then pass this request to some servlet or struts action.

Can somebody advice how to do such thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet specification doesn't give you many options. You can map your servlet to specific path (`/some/specific/path`), to all paths under some hierarchy (`/dir/*`) or to some extension (`*.action`). Best what you can do is to map your servlet to `*.action`, and then determine action to be executed based on `request.getRequestURI()` or `request.getServletPath()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Tuckey's very powerful [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). i.e.

```
<rule>
   <from>^/abra-kadabra$</from>
   <to>/admin.action</to>
</rule>
```

This rule would forward all browser requests on "/abra-kadabra" to "/admin.action" transparent to the user.